# Definite integral with negative log

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to integrate $ \int_0^1\frac {u^2 + 1}{u - 2}du$

I've calculated that this equates to $ [\frac{u^2}{2}+2u +5ln(u-2)]_0^1 $

But then I have to evaluate $ln(-1)$ and $ln(-2)$ which are obviously not defined in the real plane. I have drawn the graph and I know for certain that this integral exists. Any guidance on what I'm missing would be great.

Comment: It should be $\ln|u - 2|$, as $\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln|x| + C$.

Comment: @AlexMiller thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{u}$ is $\ln|u|$, not $\ln u$

Comment: Ahh of course - THANKS! I'm a second year BSc Maths student and I was almost about to throw all my books out of the window (this exercise is a refresher for what I did 2 years ago in high school). Funny how you forget these things. I'm so used to indefinite integrals and I omit the absolute sign.

Comment: I made this same mistake in a graduate level ODE class recently.  We all do it :)

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your integrand in the form $\frac{u^2-4}{u-2}+\frac{5}{u-2}$